# When adding grain to mash tun for second runnings, how long should I let the new grain mash?

Tags: beer, batch-sparge, partigyle

This probably illustrates my lack of knowledge about mashing in general, but I'm going to brew a barleywine with first runnings, and a stout with the second runnings.  I'm going to be adding 1 pound each of Crystal, black, and chocolate malts, and possibly a couple pounds of wheat malt after I have drawn off the wort for the barleywine.

I'm planning on adding the additional water, add the grain, stir, but then I'm lost.  On Denny's page describing batch sparging, he says immediately draw off again, but this is without additional grain, for a single beer.   How do I do this for two separate beers?

Comment: A full pound of each sounds like a bit much to me.  How many stout recipes do you see with a full pound of black malt in them?  Its a strong malt.  A half pound or less would be fine.  The amount of Crystal depends on the color.  1lb of 120L would be too strong.  Of course all of that is just my opinion.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the input.  As it turns out, my stout recipe has been brewed three times, and I love it.  You're absolutely correct, and a full pound of black is alot.  This is based off Papazian's Silver Dollar porter.  I should call it porter, but that gets into a different type of argument.

Comment: Cool then.  I'll have to look into that recipe and check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often do what you're describing when I make a barleywine.  As long as the added grains don't need to convert (and in your example they don't) you really don't need to wait at all.  At least I don't, and it works fine for me.

Comment: I would think a little time to be sure you are getting the color and flavor out of them would be advisable, no?  Like 10 min.  As opposed to add, mix and run off again.

Comment: well, it certainly won't hurt, but my experience is that it isn't necessary.

Comment: Just brewed it, and did a double batch sparge.  Color was definitely stronger in the second sparge (of the "second" runnings).  I also waited 15 minutes after adding water before draining.  So far, it's looking like a good method to me.  I think Denny is right though, I think I could get away without it, but seems like the color is benefiting, if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking correctly.   Add the grain, stir, and wait the normal amount of time you would spend to let the grain settle out.   Do your normal vorlauf and drain it into the 2nd kettle.

I think you'll need to do some extra work to get the sugars converted in the malted wheat.   I don't think you'll need to do that if you used flaked wheat instead, though.   The sugars in the crystal, black, and chocolate malts don't need to convert.  Between the stirring and vorlauf, you'll get it all mixed together well, just by virtue of the normal processes of batch sparging.